# I am running elastic search on 0.5-1 vCPU (1 shared core) GCP but the server is not able to handle how to fix this?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, devops

I am running Elasticsearch on 0.5-1 vCPU (1 shared core) with 1.7 GB of memory (GCP). When I start the elastic search service the server is crashed. How do we fix this issue? I am running Django with Postgres and Elasticsearch.

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are getting when it crashes? It is not possible to give you a useful response without knowing what the problem is

Comment: there is no error coming. ssh doest works, server does not loads , CPU usage is too high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I understand that your elastic search instance on GCP is crashing due to high CPU usage during startup**

**Follow below details which helps to diagnose and resolve the problem:**

Even if you indicated 1.7 GB of RAM and 0.5–1 vCPU, it's important to analyze the real resource consumption during startup. To do this, use [gcp cloud monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring?hl=en) to observe the metrics for CPU, Memory, and Disk utilization for your elastic instance. This will assist you in the event that during initialization any particular resource reaches its limit.

Try gaining direct access to elasticsearch logs on the VM instance even if SSH access isn't working. If at all feasible, scan the elastic search logs directory for error messages pertaining to resource allocation issues or out-of-memory faults. If monitoring confirms resource limitations consider scaling up your VM instance to a high tier with more CPU and Memory. GCP offers various [machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-resource) to choose from.

While elasticsearch appears to be the problem, make sure your Django application and Postgres database are operating well. Check their logs for any errors that could be affecting the system's overall performance.

Using elastic search on a very outdated version (0.5-1) may have known resource management problems.Therefore, for improved performance and resource efficiency, think about updating to the most recent supported elastic version.

Examine whether switching to the managed [Elasticsearch service on Google Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/partners/google-cloud) is a feasible choice. This service has automated scaling capabilities and handles resource management.